# Run method in parallel in C# and collate results

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a method that returns a object. In my parent function I have a list of IDs.

I would like to call the method for each ID I have and then have the objects added to a list. Right now I have written a loop that calls the method passing each ID and waits for the returned object and then goes to the next ID.

Can this be done in parallel? Any help here would be most helpful.

Comment: Like Parallel.ForEach() (MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
  List<int> ids = new List<int>();
  List<object> result = new List<object>();
  Parallel.ForEach(ids, (id, state, index) => {
    result.Add(new { Id = id }); // You class instance here.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **Task parallel libraries** will help you

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[2];   
tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => YourFunction());
tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => YourFunction());
Task.WaitAll(tasks);// here it will wait untill all the functions get completed
```